# htpasswd and htaccess in Plesk 9.3

Tags: .htaccess

Greetings

Here is my situation. I currently have one website on my dedicated server. As of now, I have protected the directory /exclusive using the Plesk control panel. I am having a billing company install their password management script on the server but they need the absolute location to the .htpasswd file. I can't find it or the .htaccess file. Would it be easier to unprotect the /exclusive directory and create the .htaccess file in notepad? If this is done, where should I place the .htpasswd file?

-jw

Answer (score 1):

Plesk stores their version of the htpasswd files in:

```
/var/www/vhosts/[DOMAIN]/pd
```

It appears to look and act like a normal htpasswd file. The config that declares which htpasswd file to use would be under:

```
/var/www/vhosts/[DOMAIN]/conf/httpd.include
```

Answer (score 0):

Plesk likes to put HTML files in /var/www/vhosts/[HOSTNAME]/httpdocs (or /var/www/vhosts/[HOSTNAME]/httpsdocs for sites with SSL).  Look under there for the existing .htaccess and .htpasswd files.